# Optimize memory and performance for transmit data buffer

Tags: c++, optimization, embedded

I have a function which prepares a data buffer and then sends it via an externally provided API function which looks like:

```
send(uint8_t* data_buf, uint32_t length)
```

In my particular case, my code is always sending exactly 8 bytes and the first 7 bytes are always the same (I can't change this fact; it's some sort of message header).

Because I am in an limited, embedded environment, I would like to optimize the size and performance of my code, or at least choose the best tradeoff of the two.

Currently, I see two options:

1. Create a global array. Initialize the first 7 bytes one time and then 
   just overwrite the last byte before sending the array.
2. Create a local array, write all 8 bytes and then send it.

Are there any better solutions than the two mentioned above?

Comment: How does the driver work?  Both of your solutions could fail if the driver expects to take ownership of the passed buffer, transmit it asynchronously and somehow release it later.

Comment: I don't know, it's a blackbox, but good hint if something should go wrong.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Even on an embedded system, you can count on having more than 8 *bytes* of cache. Hence performance really doesn't matter. `databuf[8]` will be fully in cache in both cases. The code size for the first case might be smaller by 2-3 instructions.

(There's often another issue: code/flash size and RAM size are distinct constraints, when you can XIP).

Comment: I wouldn't count on the cache because it ins't called in a loop or so, it is called periodically and there are other task before and after one call.

Comment: No, but in either case writing to the array pulls the whole array in cache, even if you write just the last byte. And it's then in cache for `send` to read.

Comment: I see so the access will be faster. But case 1 will still cost 8 Byte of RAM and Case 2 will have more instructions. So even I might don't need to optimize here is there another, overall better solution, to the problem behind this?

Comment: @Nicoretti: Case 2 will need 8 bytes of RAM on the stack, plus 7 in flash to serve as the source. Writing 8 bytes is just 2 instructions (32 bits store) whereas writing 1 byte may be worse (eg ARM doesn't like it, may need read-modify-write)

Comment: No, you can't count on that.  I've worked on embedded systems with networking but without cache.  Typically you don't get cache until you get into external RAM, and there are lots of embedded systems which run using on-chip memory only.  Plus it's not as if cache is free - the only way to make the operation free is to optimize it out, in the compiler or manually as the poster contemplated.